# Cannot update page - with too many characters?

Tags: pages, wp-update-post

I have problem with page update. I am tring to save more than 14230 characters. After "update" worpress is moving me to "Posts" page. I show this issue on this video: https://youtu.be/3Y8qgFEizBU

However! Sometimes I can add one chcaracter more and save it correctly! Next I cannot save more than 14231 characters. etc. Probably this is not problem with character limitation.

I tried to increase memory limit in .htaccess

```
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 1000
   php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 1000
   php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
```

I added also that line in wp-config.php

```
   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

I didnt notice this erreor earlier. I notice this after Permalink changes. And I also changed WordPress Address and Site Address to my new domain. I don't know if this is connected with the issue.

Nothing helps :(. Pls help!

Comment: try changing php_value max_input_vars to 10,000 (no comma needed)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the wp-config.php or .htaccess file you need to edit.
The problem is web server related. 
search for php.ini file in your web server directory and there are some specific limits you may need to configure.
like following keywords:
upload_max_size' , '64M' 
post_max_size', '64M'
max_execution_time', '300'
I hope it helps and feel free to explore further on your own.
Good Luck!!!

Comment: That doesnt help :((. I added inphp.ini: post_max_size=512M;
max_execution_time=300;
upload_max_filesize=1000M;
max_input_time=600;
max_input_vars=10000;
upload_max_size=64M;
memory_limit=1000M; ... and in .htaccess
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180 ... and in wp-admin.php define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3000M');

Maybe this is something connecting with my domain? This problem appears after url and direct links change.